# Adding icon.png reference to XCode?

Tags: xcode

I just spent over an hour due to yet another XCode quirck.
I added my icon.png by 'Adding an existing file' (w/ the checkbox checked for that copy option). The binary upload to AppStore kept throwing an error.

Then, I finally tried to just drag-n-drop the icon.png file into XCode. This prompted me to do the same thing (and yes, i checked that copy option thing). This allowed the binary verification to pass and consequentially the binary file got uploaded.

Question is: What did I do wrong? I didn't think there was a difference between 'Adding and existing file' and dragging the file into XCode!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you added the Icon (or Icons) reference to your info.plist?
[image]
More info here: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/qa/qa2010/qa1686.html#IPHONEADDITEMS

Comment: yeah, i did that, but not as a List. Does this mean the device will "smartly" use the proper sized icon for its resolution?

Comment: Yes the device will apparently scale it.  But it's apparently best to provide the correct resolutions.

Comment: BTW.  I believe if the file is called Icon.png (with a capital I) then it will be picked up automatically.

Comment: I also found that I had to specify every icon file with the extention, including @2x, to get xcode to recognize the icons